# How do I read data with stream builder correctly. I keep getting blank page

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck at trying to read the current user's data after storing it in Firestore. The page keeps showing a blank page instead of showing the actual data from Firestore.

I have created a model for the data like this

```
class Vital {
  String id;
  final String bloodSugar;
  final String bloodPressure;
  final String bodyTemp;
  final DateTime? createdOn;

  Vital({
    this.id = '',
    required this.bloodSugar,
    required this.bloodPressure,
    required this.bodyTemp,
    required this.createdOn,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'bloodSugar': bloodSugar,
        'bloodPressure': bloodPressure,
        'bodyTemp': bodyTemp,
        "createdOn": Utils.fromDateTimeToJson(createdOn)
      };

  

  Vital.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : id = snapshot.id,
        bloodSugar = snapshot.data()!["bloodSugar"],
        bloodPressure = snapshot.data()!["bloodPressure"],
        bodyTemp = snapshot.data()!["bodyTemp"],
        createdOn = snapshot.data()!["createdOn"].toDate();
}
```

I have stored the data in Firestore using the below code

```
Future addVitals() async {
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      final User? user = await auth.currentUser;

      final uid = user?.uid;

      final vitals = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('vitalsign')
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("usersVitals");

      final vital = Vital(
          id: vitals.id,
          createdOn: DateTime.now(),
          bloodSugar: _bloodSugar.text,
          bloodPressure: _bloodPressure.text,
          bodyTemp: _bodyTemp.text);

      final json = vital.toJson();

      await vitals.add(json);

      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VitalsSaved()));
    }
```

Please note that users will be allowed to add their vitals everyday and what I want to achieve is to get the vitals of the current users in a separate page using stream builder.

This is what I would like to achieve

```
blood pressure       
day1      day2
120/70    120/65 etc
```

blood glucose
day1       day2
27          26    etc

this will be for a specific user and once another user login to the app, they should only get their own data from what they put in the input.

This is what I have tried to do in the stream of the stream builder

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> readVitals() async* {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    final user = auth.currentUser;

    final uid = user?.uid;

    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('vitalsign')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("userVitals")
        .snapshots();
  }
```

then I created a widget as follow to get data from firestore

```
Widget buildPressure(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    document["bloodSugar"],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [Text(document["bloodPressure"])],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then lastly I use my widget in the streanbuilder as follow

```
 stream: readVitals(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Text("Loading...");
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return buildPressure(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                  });
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
```

After everything I still get a blank page which means that I am not getting any data from Firestore despite having create data and add it in Firestore.

I have tried several ways but could not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to put `.data()` in `= snapshot.data()!` in model class part.

I will give you a simple example from code of my project that may help you move on..

```
class ReadsModel {
  late String id;
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String father;
  late String mother;
  late String readDate;
  late String subType;
  late String counterNumber;
  late String paymentStatus;
  late int counterValue;

  ReadsModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.father,
    required this.mother,
    required this.readDate,
    required this.subType,
    required this.counterNumber,
    required this.paymentStatus,
    required this.counterValue,
  });

  ReadsModel.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot data){
    id = data.id;
    firstName = data['FirstName'];
    lastName = data['LastName'];
    father = data['Father'];
    mother = data['Mother'];
    readDate = data['ReadDate'];
    subType = data['Subscription type'];
    counterNumber = data['CounterNumber'];
    paymentStatus = data['Payment Status'];
    counterValue = data['CounterValue'];
  }
}
```

For the saving to Firestore part:

```
Future savingToFireStore() async {
    await villagesCollectionRef
                .doc()
                .collection('Reads')
                .doc(const Uuid().v4())
                .set({
              'FirstName': firstName,
              'LastName': lastName,
              'Father': father,
              'Mother': mother,
              'ReadDate': readDate,
              'Subscription type': subType,
              'Payment Status': 'unPaid',
              'CounterValue': int.parse(readValueController.text),
              'CounterNumber': counterNumber,
            });
  }
```

Then I create a list from the model type to store data in:

```
List<VillageModel> areaModel = <VillageModel>[].obs;
```

Then use this function to from `GetX` package to stream data and get it "You can use Stream builder in the same way"

```
getReads() {
    return villagesCollectionRef
        .doc()
        .collection('Reads')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      readsModel.clear();
      for (var element in event.docs) {
        readsModel.add(ReadsModel.fromMap(element));
      }
    });
  }
```

Finally, in the UI part you can use the suitable widget to show data, for me I used `ListView.builder()`.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me. I have been able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> readVitals() async* {
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final user = auth.currentUser;

final uid = user?.uid;

yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('vitalsign')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("userVitals")
    .snapshots();
}
```

into:

```
Stream<Iterable<Vital>> readVitals() async* {
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final user = auth.currentUser;

final uid = user?.uid;

yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('vitalsign')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("userVitals")
    .snapshots().map((event) =>
    event.docs
        .map((doc) => Vital.fromSnapshot(doc)));
}
```

This way you should return the values of the documents in the collection `UserVitals`. Note that if this documents don't have all the fields (bloodSugar, bloodPressure, bodyTemp and createdOn) you are probably gonna get an error.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been able to fix it.